# How many rovers now on Moon?

Tags: the-moon

The Apollo missions took moving rovers to the Moon. How many moving rovers are presently on the Moon?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the space exploration stack exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three lunar rovers and the Chinese Yutu rover. None of which are operational. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artificial_objects_on_the_Moon

Comment: Wow too fast I was reading the page when you posted this answer.

Comment: what about Chinese rover.. is that also not operational now?

Comment: @RANSARA009 The [Chinese rover Yutu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yutu_(rover)) recently stopped working on July 31st 2016. Before that is was unable to move and transmitting data from its final resting location.